# How can i return to my menu after executing a method?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, menu

```
package javaapplication10;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Tom
 */
public class JavaApplication10 {
static int randomWithRange(int min, int max)
{
   int range = (max - min) + 1;     
   return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
public static void menu(){
    System.out.println("MENU:");
    System.out.println("1.Questions");
    System.out.println("2.High Scores");
    System.out.println("3.Exit");
    }//creates the function "menu" with 3 different options

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    String userName = scanner.next();//stores the user's name as the variable userName
    System.out.println("What class are you in "+userName+"? (1, 2 or 3");
    int userClass = scanner.nextInt();

    menu();//outputs the function "menu"
    System.out.println("Please choose an option from the menu:");
    int menuChoice = scanner.nextInt();//stores the integer that the user has entered as the menuChoice


    int[] highScores1 = new int[30];
    int[] highScores2 = new int[30];
    int[] highScores3 = new int[30];
    String[] Names = new String[30];
    boolean run = true;

    ArrayList calc = new ArrayList();//stores all the operations in an array list
    calc.add("+");
    calc.add("-");
    calc.add("*");

    while(menuChoice != 3){
    switch(menuChoice){
        case 1://if the menuChoice = 1 it carries out te following code

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Please answer the following questions:");
        System.out.println("This test will involve some negative answers so watch out for them!");
        System.out.println(" ");

        int counter = 0;//starts the counter at 0
        int counter1 = 0;
        int score = 0;

        Names[counter1] = userName;

        for (int i = 1; i<11; i++){
            int randomnr = randomWithRange(10,0);//creates a random number with the max number being 10
            int randomnr2 = randomWithRange(10,0);
            int randomcalc = randomWithRange(0,2);
            System.out.println("Question "+i+": "+randomnr+" "+calc.get(randomcalc)+" "+randomnr2);
            System.out.print("Enter the correct answer: ");
            int answer = scanner.nextInt();


            if (randomcalc == 0){
                int calculation = randomnr+randomnr2;
                if(answer == calculation){
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    counter++;
                    score++;
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Wrong, "+calculation+" is the correct answer");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }
            if (randomcalc == 1){
                int calculation = randomnr-randomnr2;
                if(answer == calculation){
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    counter++;
                    score++;
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Wrong, "+calculation+" is the correct answer");
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }
            if (randomcalc == 2){
                int calculation = randomnr*randomnr2;
                if(answer == calculation){
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    counter++;
                    score++;
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Wrong, "+calculation+" is the correct answer");
                    System.out.println(" ");

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations "+userName+", you  have scored "+counter+"/10");

        if(counter <= 3){
            System.out.println("You need to work harder!");
        }
        else if(counter <= 6 && counter > 3){
            System.out.println("Keep putting in the work and you will start getting those top grades!");
        }
        else if(counter <= 9 && counter > 8){
            System.out.println("Unlucky! With a little more revision you can achieve those top marks!");
        }
        else if(counter <= 0){
            System.out.println("Are you drunk?!");
        }
        else if(counter == 10){
            System.out.println("Well done "+userName+", your work has clearly paid off, top marks!");
        }

        highScores1[counter1] = counter;
            counter++;
        highScores2[counter1] = counter;
            counter++;
        highScores3[counter1] = counter;
            counter++;
                break;



        case 2:
            if(userClass == 1){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Names));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highScores1));
            }

            if(userClass == 2){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Names));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highScores1));
            }

            if(userClass == 3){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Names));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highScores3));   
            }
                break;


        case 3:
            System.out.println("Please come back soon!");
            run = false;
    }






    }


}
}
```

I have written this code and i am struggling to return to the menu after the code has been executed. Also with my case 2, it prints the arrays continuously and i was wondering how to print the contents of the array once and then return to the menu again. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method menu by saying "menu()" just like you would with any other method.

```html
if(x ==2){ 
  menu(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the menu selection within the while() loop, just after the switch() statement ends and before the closing brace of the while loop. Adding:

```
menu();
System.out.println("Please choose an option from the menu:");
menuChoice = scanner.nextInt();
```

... at this point should do it.

Note, this also means there's no point in having the "case 3" bit in your switch statement - just put that bit of code outside the while loop. You will find it easier to read these code blocks if you refactor some of this code from the switch statement into its own methods.

Comment: Thank you, that seems quite obvious now however I am fairly new to programming!